# Angular6 Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<...[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, http, httpclient

*Context to my problem*: I am trying to make an http request in the typescript part of my Angular app. I am just trying to call the localhost:5000 for data from my Python REST API.

I believe the following two components are all that is needed to solve this problem. I just can't see what can be replace or installed to fix this. Please let me know.

exam.model.ts

```
// TS class to represent coordinate data

 export class Exam {
     constructor(
      public Company: string,
      public HireDate: string, // should be changed to date
      public Title: string,
      public Location: string,
      public Degree: string,
      public yearEnteredWorkForce: string, // should be changed to date
      public OfferCostNumber: string,
      public bonus: string,
      public latitude: number,
      public longitude: number
    ) { }
  }
```

exam-api.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {API_URL} from '../env';
import {Exam} from './exam.model';

@Injectable()
export class ExamsApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  private static _handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
    return Observable.throw(err.message || 'Error: Unable to complete request.');
  }

  // GET list of public, future events
  getExams(): Observable<Exam[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(`${API_URL}/data`)
      .catch(ExamsApiService._handleError);
  }
}
```

Here is the entire error I am getting:

```
ERROR in src/app/http-example/exam-api.service.ts(20,5): error TS2322:     Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Exam[]>'.
  Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Exam[]'.
    The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
      Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Object'.
```

Comment: By default `http.get` is an observable of an object. Your method signature says you should get back an observable of an *array*, which is a different type. You should specify the type of the response object so TS can help you: https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned 'Exam' Class is not assignable to Observable, as class cannot be used a interface.

Make a interface like this :

```
export interface Exam {
  Company: string,
  HireDate: string,
  Title: string,
  Location: string,
  Degree: string,
  yearEnteredWorkForce: string, 
  OfferCostNumber: string,
  bonus: string,
  latitude: number,
  longitude: number
```

}

Then use it in Observable type.

Try This!!, Hope this should help

Comment: Hey Thanks! Didn't work though. I'm getting the same error still.

Comment: Were there any other changes that were supposed to also be made?

Comment: Why do you think they don't already have this type, given that they're using it? And this doesn't tell the OP how to actually use this with the client.

Comment: I think you need to replace Observable<Exam[]> with Observable<HttpResponse<any>>

Comment: I think you need to replace Observable<Exam[]> with Observable<HttpResponse<any>>... That will remove the error and at the time of subscription to the observable use above mentioned interface as response type..

Comment: @DanishArora that's completely backwards, they need to make the type *more* like what they're actually receiving, not *less*. You would also need to pass another option to the HTTP client for that to be the correct return type.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: So, In that case i guess, i have written right "At the time of subscription to the observable use above mentioned interface as response type", Which states that your response return type will be according to the interface "Exam".